# Two Interacting C# Classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interaction

This is a pretty beginner question but I'm stumped and I can't figure out how to get what I want from this. I have my first class that obtains information (database/textfile/whatever) but I want it to relay that information into Class2.

For instance, the first:

```
 public class Class1
{
    private int first;
    private string firstString;
    private bool isTrue;

    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
        first = 1;
        firstString = "FirstString";
        isTrue = true;
    }
}
```

Here `SomeMethod` sets all the attributes that I need to pass into Class2.

ClassTwo looks like

```
  public class Class2
{
    private int first;
    private string FirstString;
    private bool isTrue;

    private int second;
    private string SecondString;
    private bool isFalse;

    public void SomeOtherMethod() 
    {

    }
}
```

Here what I want is for `SomeOtherMethod()` to set the first set of attributes with the values that were set in Class1's `SomeMethod()`. So that I can create an object of type `Class2` and add what I want to it.

Comment: Why doesn't `Class2` *contain* `Class1`, rather than your recapitulating all its properties?  Do you have a reason?  Otherwise, it seems you should be looking at [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: I think you'd want a `List<Class1>` in `Class2` instead of repeating all the fields *that many times*.

Comment: The question is unclear, but he could simply be wanting an Adapter.

Comment: @KirkWoll I want to keep them separate because one will be used as a database manager whilst the other will use the information gathered for other purposes.

Comment: @AlvinWong How can I get a list of Class1 objects in my Class2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some other commentators stated, you really should reuse your data definitions.  Something like this can get you started:

```
public class Class1
{
    private int _myInt;
    private string _myString;
    private bool _myBool;

    public void SomeMethod() 
    {
        _myInt = 1;
        _myString = "FirstString";
        _myBool = true;
    }
}

public Class2
{
    private Class1 _first = new Class1();
    private Class1 _second = new Class1();

    public void SetFirst(Class1 obj)
    {
       _first = obj;
    }
}
```

and then use the classes like this:

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
Class2 c2 = new Class2();

c1.SomeMethod();
c2.SetFirst(c1);
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you, I think my brain is blocking, this is exactly all I needed!

Comment: you are welcome.  I also suffer from the brain blocking thing :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define [get accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786.aspx) for the properties of Class1 because they are all unreachable from outside the class and Class2 needs to use their values. Defining public properties with get accessors can be useful:

```
private int first;
public int First
{
    get
    {
        return first;
    }
}
```

Having every property in Class1 defined like this, you can access the values. After calling SomeMethod, two objects' properties can be equalized in two simple ways (See also: [Signatures and overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131.aspx)):

```
public void SomeOtherMethod() 
{
    Class1 tempClass = new Class1();
    tempClass.SomeMethod();

    this.first = tempClass.first;
    this.FirstString = tempClass.firstString;
    this.isTrue = tempClass.isTrue;
}

public void SomeOtherMethod(Class1 myClass) // Overloaded method
{
    this.first = myClass.first;
    this.FirstString = myClass.firstString;
    this.isTrue = myClass.isTrue;
}
```

Even though the techniques above seem like to be what you asked for, the best is to initialize a class's properties using [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173115.aspx). This way, you don't have to call SomeMethod each time you create a Class1 object, and you can also set its default values whenever a new one is created. Also, giving more general names to the properties will save you from duplicates. I write some code to provide you an understandable syntax that will prevent future problems of non-accessibility and repetition.

```
public class Class1
{
    private int number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
    }

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }

    private bool isTrue;
    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return isTrue; }
    }

    public Class1()
    {
        number = 1;
        name = "FirstString";
        isTrue = true;
    }

    public Class1(int value1, string value2, bool value3)
    {
        number = value1;
        name = value2;
        isTrue = value3;
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    private Class1 firstClass;
    private Class1 secondClass;

    public Class2()
    {
        firstClass = new Class1();
        secondClass = new Class1(2, "SecondString", false);
    }
}
```

If you're going to define many Class1 objects in Class2, then a solution such as an array or a list becomes must. I'll give a short example, see [MSDN List page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

```
private List<Class1> class1List = new List<Class1>();
class1List.Add(new Class1());
class1List.Add(new Class1(2, "SecondString", false));
```